# ConTeXt: Can I print a PDF document with fillable forms?

Tags: luatex, pdf, tex-core, context, printing

When I try to print PDFs achieved with ConTeXt that have fillable forms, when I fill in the form, what I have filled in does not appear in the print. Is there any way to get that once filled they remain for printing?

Comment: Welcome to this site! I don't think your question is specific to ConTeXt, is it? I would imagine that it depends on your PDF viewer more than anything else. Do you experience this issue only with PDFs generated by ConTeXt and not with other PDFs that have fillable forms?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you very much for your answer! Well, I imagine that PDF has an option to print forms, in its API, and perhaps ConTeXt had a specific command to allow it. They are just assumptions, maybe it is a question of the PDF viewer. In any case, if so, do you know of any that allow this? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I have achieved what I wanted, in the `\setupfield` the option must be added: `option = printable`
The example that appears in the `\setupfield` [ConTeXt Garden Wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefield)  runs perfectly:

```
\usemodule[fields] % MkIV
\setupfield[shortString][reset,horizontal][width=45mm,option=printable,frame=off,bottomframe=on,height=2em,offset=0.5mm,frameoffset=1mm]
\definefield[Name][line][shortString][][Hans]
\field[Name]
```

It's a cool feature, I'm really liking ConTeXt!